# Check if a value from one array exists in another array using linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I've got an list where myclass is defined with a few properties

```
List<MyClass> myClassList = new List<MyClass>();
myClassList.Add(new MyClass() { Id = 1, Name = "My first test", Key = "First" });
myClassList.Add(new MyClass() { Id = 2, Name = "My second test", Key = "Second" });
```

I then have a path i.e. c:\my folders\company name\My First Test, which I break into a string array using regex i.e. myArrayPath

I want to find if any elements of myClassList based on a given property i.e. Name can be found in any of the elements from myArrayPath and ideally I'd like to return the Key but if I return the object matching one of the element from myArrayPath, this will be just as good.

Is there a way to achieve this using linq and/or lambda expressions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be quite easily done with LINQ:

```
var keyResult = myClassList.Where(x=>myArrayPath.Contains(x.Name))
    .Select(x=>x.Key);
```

if you need it in the form of a list of an array, just add `.ToList()` or .`ToArray()` at the end of it.

Comment: Spot on!! I've just changed the above code slightly to return the actual key as all values in both arrays will be unique, so no need for a list to be returned. string key = myClassList.Where(x=>myArrayPath.Contains(x.Name))
    .Select(x=>x.Key).First();