# Check all values in Array1 exist in values of array2?

Tags: c#

Let say I have,

```
class A
{
    string[] values;
}

class B
{
    string[] values;
}
```

and I have 2 object,

```
var a= new A{ values ={"a","b","c"}}
var b= new A{ values ={"b","c"}}
```

How do I make sure that all values of B should exist in A.values in efficient way?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921673/check-if-a-value-from-one-array-exists-in-another-array-using-linq

Comment: It's strange that - as a user with quite a lot questions and answers - you didn't show any effort in researching your question and trying something on your own...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to check whether set A contains set B.
To do this, you produce the set difference between the two sets using [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX), and check whether the difference contains any elements.

```
var contains = ! b.values.Except(a.values).Any();
```

These things are easier if you imagine a Venn diagram.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to get unique items from `b` which don't exist in `a` (this is a set operation, so its pretty efficient). Then use [Enumerable.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb337697%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to check if there is no such items. If there is no unique items from `b` which don't exist in `a`, then all items in `b` exist in `a`:

```
bool allExist = !b.values.Except(a.values).Any();
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED** :

```
List<string> listA = new List<string>(a);
List<string> listB = new List<string>(b);
var listCommon = listA.Where(listB.Contains);
```

Comment: this will check that at least 1 value in common but OP wants all values